# v-model not working in laravel vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I am using ElementUI in Laravel app, the problem I am facing is that the v-model directive is not working. I have tried putting normal input as well but the v-model directive still does not work.

```js
export default {
  props: ['cardHeading'],
  data() {
    return {
      formData: {
        name: 'asdf',
        password: ''
      },
      csrfToken: window.Laravel.csrfToken
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm(formName) {
      this.$refs[formName].validate((valid) => {
        if (valid) {
          alert('submit!');
        } else {
          console.log('error submit!!');
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.formData);
  }
}
```

```html
<el-form ref="form" label-position="right" :model="formData" label-width="100px">
  <h1>{{cardHeading}}</h1>
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrfToken">
  <el-form-item label="Email: ">
    <el-input type="email" v-model="formData.name"></el-input>
  </el-form-item>
  <el-form-item label="Password: ">
    <el-input type="password" suffix-icon="fa-icon-view" v-model="formData.password"></el-input>
  </el-form-item>
  <el-form-item>
    <el-button type="primary" round>Create<i class="el-icon-d-arrow-right"></i></el-button>
  </el-form-item>
</el-form>
```

[image]

Comment: The snippet tool as an button `Tidy`  that formats your code and that makes it easier to read.

Comment: I did Tidy it can you help me now? @t.niese

Comment: Not I can't help you because I currently can't check where the problem might be. And it you take a look at the edit history you can see that I did the code formatting before I wrote the comment. Not sure what you did it wasn't using `Tidy`. Anyhow I just informed you about it that you know that for future questions.

Comment: Are you using vue? i dont see the imports there

Comment: Maybe I don't know ElementUI, but where's formName defined and where's submitForm called?

Comment: have you read the docs yet? you dont seem to ...

Comment: I am using Vue, but the vue is imported in app.js file and this is a vue component called LoginComponent.vue, now when I am putting some data in the `export default` object as you can see and trying to use it in `<el-input type="email" v-model="formData.name"></el-input>` the data does not show up and the input remains empty and the `@click` event handler isn't working in the button as well.

Comment: @Geomorillo Yes I have read the docs and used exactly what was written in the docs.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: unexpected syntax

Comment: No everything else is working perfectly fine, there are no errors in the console.

Comment: @Geomorillo where is the unexpected Syntax?

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 25,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: well in the snippet code

Comment: It won't work in the snippet, because it has dependencies like Element-UI

Comment: well then how im suppose to test it since i dont have your full project ?

Comment: Let me see if I can do something like making a github repo of this project and you can clone it

Comment: only the ui part please

Comment: No, I'd say put the whole project in because there might be something that gets missed. Just point out what the relevant files are.

Comment: https://github.com/looney-toon/legacy-app

Comment: You can get the code from here, the problem is in the LoginController, this is a laravel app so you will have to do the necessary installations using composer and for vue to run you need to do npm installations as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the issue but it's definitely *an* issue.

In your `layouts/app.blade.php` your loading `app.js` twice. I would suggest removing the one in the `head` on line 15:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```